# Change download filename codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Convert file name before force download.

I am trying to be able to convert the file name of the stored file name to the orignal file name before download

So when user clicks on a file to download instead of showing

```
post_1486965530_jeJNHKWXPMrwRpGBYxczIfTbaqhLnDVO.php
```

Like in image below

It will just rename the downloaded file something like

```
config.php
```

[image]

> Question how to only change the downloaded filename when click on image.

```
public function downloads($id) {
    $this->db->where('attachment_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('attachments');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
       return false;
    }

    $path = '';
    $file = '';

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

        $path .= FCPATH . 'uploads/'; 

        // This gives the stored file name
        // This is folder 201702
        // Looks like 201702/post_1486965530_jeJNHKWXPMrwRpGBYxczIfTbaqhLnDVO.php

        $stored_file_name .= $result['attachment_name']; 

        // Out puts just example "config.php"
        $original .= $result['file_name']; 

    }

    force_download($path . $stored_file_name, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that 
(imho your foreach loop doesn't make any sense)

```
public function downloads($id) {
    $this->db->where('attachment_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('attachments');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
       return false;
    }

    $path = '';
    $file = '';

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

        $path .= FCPATH . 'uploads/'; 

        // This gives the stored file name
        // This is folder 201702
        // Looks like 201702/post_1486965530_jeJNHKWXPMrwRpGBYxczIfTbaqhLnDVO.php

        $stored_file_name .= $result['attachment_name']; 

        // Out puts just example "config.php"
        $original .= $result['file_name']; 

    }

    force_download("your_filename.txt",file_get_contents($path . $stored_file_name));
}
```

Comment: That works fine but what you mean foreach loop make no sense if have a better way add that.

Comment: the question which comes to mind is , what happens if you have more than one result here ? 
in this case this function won't work anymore

Comment: What about using row_array() like                                        `$attachment = $query->row_array();
$path = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
$original = $attachment['file_name'];
$stored_file_name = $attachment['attachment_name'];` seems to work fine when I click on each file

Answer (score 1):

Simple like that!

```
force_download(
    $filenameWithFileExtension, 
    file_get_contents($fileToDownload), 
    mime_content_type($fileToDownload)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this situation use force_download() something like this -

```
$file_name = "using md5 to convert it on normal text and stroe variable";
$file_path = "It's your file path, where have file in your drive"
$file_path = 'uploads/'.$path; 
force_download($file_name, file_get_contents($file_path));
```

It's simple and working fine. Just need to store your file path and file name store in 2 different variables and pass them in force_download().
Hope it's work.
Good Luck.